# Parameter showing NULL in Get handler in .net core 3

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core-3.1

I am working on an application with a requirement to fetch data from sql server DB and show it on a page. I am very new to .net core 3. 
So far I can fetch my data and show it using datatable. I tested with hard-coded value. Now when i am trying to send the search string from front-end , the value is coming as null. I am not sure where i am going wrong in this.

This is my code so far -

Get Data logic -

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetDataMatrix(string SearchString)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchString))
            {

                var res = await _dbContext.DbSetModel.Where(x => x.SQuery.Contains(SearchString)).ToListAsync();
                foreach (var item in res)
                {
                    MyViewModel cmVm = new MyViewModel
                    {
                        // Mapping ViewModel data with "res" data
                    };
                    VMList.Add(cmVm); // creating a list with Viewmodel
                }


            }
            return new JsonResult(new { data = cmVMList });
        }
```

This is the UI - --------------------------------------

```
<form method="post">
            <div class="col-xs-10">
                <div class="form-group mr-2">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" id="srchTxt" name="SearchString" class="form-control" />
                        <label id="lblStxt" style="visibility:hidden; color:red"></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Get Data</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </form>
```

I am hitting the Get Handler everything the page opens up. But not able to pass this parameter to that method. I am sure it is simply. Even checked a few forums. Did not work. I am have not tried JS though. I think if it is possible from the HTML part then no need to use JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controllers work with data that comes from HTTP requests. By default, it sets to **key-value** pairs. You can change the source by specifying a source.
by adding **[FromForm]** attribute you can specify to read data from a form.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetDataMatrix([FromForm] string SearchString)
```

I hope it helps

Comment: @JK1990 Happy to help